# How to put a background onto its own Render Layer?

Tags: render-layers, world, viewlayers

I'm working with a 3rd-party product that allows you to create custom skies via Blender's World environment. The documentation states:

"To render fast you can separate the background on a render layer and use 1 sample per pixel to speed up render times. This way you get a Full HD Image in a matter of seconds."

**QUESTION: How do you put the background (World Environment?) onto its own render layer?**

I know how to separate collections onto render layers, but this background thing has me stumped. I've researched it to no avail. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.1.2, Windows 11.

[product documentation](https://blendermarket.com/products/nm-8-skies/docs)

[image]

Comment: if you disable all the collections for a given view layer, it will render only the background, is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I want to render everything, but according to the product's documentation I can put the background onto its own layer with its own render settings for faster overall rendering.

Comment: what do you mean by "put the background into its own layer"?

Comment: That's what the product documentation says, and that's what I'm trying to figure out. :)

Comment: Hi :). Just FYI - This approach was useful in previous versions, but now Cycles automatically renders world background with one sample thanks to adaptive sampling :)

Comment: (and the docs seem poorly written, since both environment and sampling are set *per scene*, not per render layer :))

Comment: Thanks everybody for the responses. I think I understand now. Much appreciated!